# SQL Select rows with max and min date

Tags: sql

I am trying to get 2 rows from a table at one shot. The one with the minimum datetime (today - 7) of last week and the one which is the latest (today).
My table:

```
|id  |dataIn |dataOut|date                   |MachineId                            |
-----+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
|1   |5006   |58     |2011-10-25 09:03:17.000|7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559  
|2   |1200   |130    |2011-10-26 12:45:43.000|7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559 
        ...  
|124 |1350   |480    |2011-10-29 13:29:04.000|7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559  
|125 |8005   |560    |2011-10-31 21:18:35.000|7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559
```

I can select the data from last week with:

```sql
SELECT 
dbo.myDatabase.Date AS [date], dbo.myDatabase.dataIn AS [in], 
dbo.myDatabase.dataOut AS [out] 
FROM 
dbo.myDatabase WHERE 
Date >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0) 
AND 
dbo.myDatabase.MachineId = '7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559'
```

but I would only like row 1 AND 125 because those are the rows used for my calculations.
So my question is:
How do I select the 2 rows (with MIN and MAX date) from within the results of the previous query?

Comment: There could be more than one row with the min or max date. What do you want to do then?

Comment: does the date/time stamp directly correlate to the apparent auto-increment ID column???

Comment: @TimRogers No. Each machine inserts a row with the datetime when there is a change, so its unique / machine

Comment: @DRapp There is no correlation. What I am simply trying to do is get the total IN and total Out for the week, which is the difference between the dataIn/dataOut of the first and last row within the last 7 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this:

```
select * from dbo.myDatabase 
where 
    ([Date] = (select max([Date]) from /* your query */ ) or 
    [Date] = (select min([Date]) from /* your query */ ))
    and MachineId = '7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559' -- or any other id
```

**Edit:** since it's entirely possible that two machines have the same `date` value, the query should be updated to also include a `MachineId` filter in the `where` clause. I updated the query to show this.

Comment: see clarification in my answer... your query that relies exclusively on the Date being equal would work, but would also return multiple records for anything that matched the given date -- even across different machines sending the data.

Comment: @DRapp I see your point about this returning everything that matched the date, even across different `MachineId`. I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: how would you do it if you had groups  - meaning there is a max(date) for each group ...

Answer (score 5):

In case you ever have multiple rows with an identical date, this query will make sure only one row is returned for the min / max (only for Sql 2005+).

```
;WITH dates 
     AS (SELECT dbo.Mydatabase(id)                    AS id, 
                dbo.mydatabase.DATE                   AS [date], 
                dbo.mydatabase.datain                 AS [in], 
                dbo.mydatabase.dataout                AS [out], 
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS row 
         FROM   dbo.mydatabase 
         WHERE  DATE >= Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, 0, Getdate()) - 7, 0) 
                AND dbo.mydatabase.machineid = 
                    '7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559'), 
     dates2 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                DATE, 
                in, 
                OUT, 
                row, 
                MIN(row) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)) AS lowest_row, 
                MAX(row) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)) AS highest_row 
         FROM   dates) 
SELECT id, 
       DATE, 
       in, 
       OUT 
FROM   dates2 
WHERE  row = lowest_row 
        OR row = highest_row
```

Comment: +1 but you could probably add another field to Row_number (e.g. `ORDER BY DATE ASC , dbo.Mydatabase(id) ASC`) to make the tiebreaker more deterministic.

Comment: If the windowed aggregate function is applied to the entire rowset, you can simply omit the `PARTITION BY` clause (for instance: `MIN (row) OVER () AS lowest_row`).

Comment: @Andriy M - is there likely to be any performance gain through ommitting the PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)? Personally I find using that more readable, but thatg could be just me!

Comment: @Davin: Hard to say, partly due to the fact that I've probably never encountered `PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)` before. I wouldn't expect any difference, though.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments, and each machine doing its own INSERT, the insert wouldn't be inserting a value for the auto-increment column as that is handled by the engine.  So, unless the machine is changing its date/time, there IS a direct correlation to the auto-increment ID to the date/time on a PER MACHINE basis.  So, that said, and the sample I've created which gets the minimum and maximum ID per the MACHINE where the date/time is qualified WILL result in the definitive first and last ID for the range in question. Then you can get the specific ID records.

So, if you have 3 machines, and they do an insert at exact same time, their respective IDs would be generated differently...

```
|id  |date                   |MachineId                            |
-----+-------+-------+-----------------
|1   |2011-10-25 09:03:17.000| A
|2   |2011-10-25 09:03:17.000| B
|3   |2011-10-25 09:03:17.000| C

|4   |2011-10-26 12:45:43.000| B
|5   |2011-10-26 12:45:43.000| A
|6   |2011-10-26 12:45:43.000| C

        ...  

|124 |2011-10-29 13:29:04.000| C
|125 |2011-10-29 13:29:04.000| A
|126 |2011-10-29 13:29:04.000| B

|127 |2011-10-31 21:18:35.000| C
|128 |2011-10-31 21:18:35.000| B
|129 |2011-10-31 21:18:35.000| A

The first and last IDs per respective machine would become
Machine First ID   Last ID
A         1         129
B         2         128
C         3         127
```

The inner pre-query is done once (PER THE SPECIFIC MACHINE), so you are getting the ID associated with the first/last instance per the machine date/time period.  Then join that back to the table for the actual data with OR on the ID match.

```
select 
      D2.*
   FROM
      ( SELECT 
              min( D1.ID ) MinDateID,
              max( D1.ID ) MaxDateID
           from
              dbo.myDatabase D1
           where
                  D1.MachineId = '7B788EE88E-6527-4CB4-AA4D-01B7F4048559' 
              AND D1.Date >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
      ) PreQuery
      JOIN dbo.MyDatabase D2
         on PreQuery.MinDateID = D2.ID
         OR PreQuery.MaxDateID = D2.ID
```

Comment: as per OP's comment on the question, the `ID`s don't correlate to the min and max dates. With a small change to select the min and max dates, however, this also works.

Comment: @user798612, see clarification in answer per sample data context