# How to show all data when post data is empty mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that runs when a user submits a start and end date.  I would like the table to populate first if the form has not been submitted.  If user goes to /records.php it should show all records.  Then user can filter with the form to the between dates he wants.  Right now the filter works fine but when a user visits the page no data loads.

```
if(!isset($_GET['datemin'])){

$query_date = date("Y/m/d");

      // First day of the month.
$mindate = date("M d, Y", strtotime("first day of previous month"));

      // Last day of the month.
$maxdate = date('M d, Y', strtotime("last day of previous month"));
}else{


$date = new DateTime($_GET['datemin']);
$mindate = $date->format('M d, Y');

$date = new DateTime($_GET['datemax']);
$maxdate = $date->format('M d, Y');

}

SELECT
*
FROM records RQ
AND Sold_On BETWEEN "'.$mindate.'" AND "'.$maxdate.'"
```

How do I go about getting this to load all data for records without using the form?  Then have them filter as they see fit? Any direction on how I would search what I am looking for is also helpful so I can read up on this.

The above script currently grabs last month data.  I would like it to show ALL data though.  Could be 4 months or 4 years old.

Comment: I highly suggest going with PDO. Specifically pdo::query, but I would start with learning the ropes using PDO https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: @dalelandry Thank you for that input.  I know PDO and how to use it.  The client does not want to use PDO .  He wants to stick with mysqli.  Believe me its a headache Plus I'm not sure what that has to do with my question.

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` then assign your $row values to an variable and display them in a table. Wrap the values in a tag for selection by user.

Comment: Are you saying your sql is not grabbing all the records? Ia ssume you are not having trouble displaying the array persay, but the issue is retrieving all the records?

Comment: Have you scoped this question in SO yet?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967010/sql-select-rows-with-max-and-min-date

Comment: Perhaps posting a table of your DB may help others help you out

Comment: This isn't really mysqli. The point about mysqli was that it allowed the use of prepared and bound queries. That said, it would be useful to see an echo of the query as it presently stands.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cbdb/3  This fiddle shows minimal data than what I have but its to the point.  if page loads initially I want all data from all rows to show.  then when user submits to filter it shows just the date range